Coding a customizable JRPG random action system in Godot 4?
I'm making an open source turn based JRPG in Godot 4.3, I want any programmer to be able to very easily create new enemies with different behaviors by simply customizing export variables in the editor, There's currently 3 Actions the enemies can do: Attack, Strong Attack, Do nothing.
I want it so that each enemy can have a specific chance to do each action, So for example there could be a "Lazy" enemy that has an 80% chance to do nothing and a 20% chance to actually attack, Another enemy could be "Aggressive" with a 75% chance to attack and a 25% to do a strong attack.
But I'm having trouble implementing this system, I'm attempting to use @export_range and have users just increase the chances of each action happening, But that didn't work so easily:
#Every enemy has this data
@export_category("Chance for actions")
@export_range(0.01, 1.00) var attackingChance
@export_range(0.01, 1.00) var strongAttackingChance

    if !enemyGettingReadyForStrongAttack:
        var action: float = randf()
        if action <= enemyData.attackingChance:
            enemy_attack()
        elif action <= enemyData.strongAttackingChance:
            enemy_strong_attack_prep()
        else:
            enemy_nothing()
    else:
        enemy_strong_attack()


This current system works when I only have 2 actions those being an action that can the user can manipulate the chance of + a default action, So the user can set the attacking chance to 65% and if randf() returns 0.65 or below then the enemy will attack and if it doesn't then it'll just default to doing nothing.
But this won't work when more than 2 actions are active, The if statement prioritizes the 1st if and skips the other elifs if the 1st if just turns out to be true, So If I have the attacking chance be 60% and strong attacking be 40% and randf() returns 0.61 to 1.00 then the enemy will default to doing nothing, But if randf() returns 0.01 to 0.60 then the if statement will just do the normal attack and never do the strong attack since the if statement has a certain order.
I'm really not sure how to code this system ! Please tell me any ideas you have, I'm ready to just rewrite the whole system if necessary.

It appears that you have two issues, the first (normalization) is that the user may not enter in % values that add up to 100%. There is a quick fix for this, which is that you can total up the percentages and divide all the user entered values by the total, hence the "normalized" values will now add up to 1 (100%).
Now lets say you have normalized percentages for four actions (A,B,C & D):

A - 20%
B - 31%
C - 25%
D - 24%

Next you generate a random number p in the range: 0.0 - 0.999999...
You then just do an if condition with ranges based on the accumulation of the percentages:
if p < 0.2:
    actionA()
elif p < 0.51:
    actionB()
elif p < 0.76:
    actionC()
else
    actionD()

You need to calculate the accumulation values, by summing up all the previous actions. For example the real conditions will use variables not constants, something like:
// Optional: move these calculations to an @OnReady section.
var accum_pA = pA
var accum_pB = pB + accum_pA
var accum_pC = pC + accum_pB

...

if p < accum_pA:
    actionA()
elif p < accum_pB:
    actionB()
elif p < accum_pC:
    actionC()
else
    actionD()

Note: The beginning of each range is implied due to the structure of the if/elif/else block.

As a reference, I have manually fixed the other LLM answer - removing the normalization step, as it is incorrect if there is an implied idle action, I am not sure if having an implied idle is "better" I would probably explicitly specify the idle percentage and normalize, but this is a matter of opinion, so I will present it as another option.
Anyway here is the fixed code - with implied idle:
# Note: No idle percentage have been given, it is implied that any remainder is idle time.
@export_range(0.0, 1.0) var attackingChance: float
@export_range(0.0, 1.0) var strongAttackingChance: float
@export_range(0.0, 1.0) var defendingChance: float
@export_range(0.0, 1.0) var magicChance: float

# Because of the implied idle, the normalization step must be removed
# Only accumulated percentages are calculated.
var accumulatedAttackingChance: float
var accumulatedStrongAttackingChance: float
var accumulatedDefendingChance: float
var accumulatedMagicChance: float

func _ready():
    accumulate_action_chances()

func accumulate_action_chances():
    var total_chance = attackingChance + strongAttackingChance + defendingChance + magicChance
    
    if total_chance <= 0.0:
        push_error("Total chance is 0! Set at least one action chance.")
        return

    if total_chance > 1.0:
        push_error("Total chance is > 1! Adjust the percentages")
        return

    # Accumalate percentages
    accumulatedAttackingChance = attackingChance
    accumulatedStrongAttackingChance = strongAttackingChance + accumulatedAttackingChance
    accumulatedDefendingChance = defendingChance + accumulatedStrongAttackingChance
    accumulatedMagicChance = magicChance + accumulatedDefendingChance


func perform_action():
    # "Slightly" incorrect because randf() is documented to return the range 0.0 - 1.0 (inclusive).
    # In practice this discrepancy won't matter.
    var action = randf()

    # Attack action
    if action < accumulatedAttackingChance:
        action_attack()
        # Using return instead of elif/else blocks...
        return

    # Strong attack action
    if action < accumulatedStrongAttackingChance:
        action_strong_attack_prep()
        return

    # Defend action
    if action < accumulatedDefendingChance:
        enemy_defend()
        return

    # Magic action
    if action < accumulatedMagicChance:
        action_cast_magic()
        return

    # Default to doing nothing if no action matches
    action_idle()


I tried asking ChatGPT and I think it gave me some good code ? I'm too tired to try it now though
@export_range(0.0, 1.0) var attackingChance: float
@export_range(0.0, 1.0) var strongAttackingChance: float
@export_range(0.0, 1.0) var defendingChance: float
@export_range(0.0, 1.0) var magicChance: float

func _ready():
    normalize_action_chances()

func normalize_action_chances():
    var total_chance = attackingChance + strongAttackingChance + defendingChance + magicChance
    
    if total_chance == 0.0:
        push_error("Total chance is 0! Set at least one action chance.")
        return

    # Normalize to make the sum 1.0
    attackingChance /= total_chance
    strongAttackingChance /= total_chance
    defendingChance /= total_chance
    magicChance /= total_chance

func choose_action():
    var action = randf()
    var lower_bound = 0.0

    # Attack action
    var upper_bound = lower_bound + attackingChance
    if action >= lower_bound and action < upper_bound:
        enemy_attack()
        return

    # Strong attack action
    lower_bound = upper_bound
    upper_bound = lower_bound + strongAttackingChance
    if action >= lower_bound and action < upper_bound:
        enemy_strong_attack_prep()
        return

    # Defend action
    lower_bound = upper_bound
    upper_bound = lower_bound + defendingChance
    if action >= lower_bound and action < upper_bound:
        enemy_defend()
        return

    # Magic action
    lower_bound = upper_bound
    upper_bound = lower_bound + magicChance
    if action >= lower_bound and action < upper_bound:
        enemy_cast_magic()
        return

    # Default to doing nothing if no action matches
    enemy_nothing()


So you did't just let a large language model generate this answer, you didn't even check if it actually works?

This came across my low-quality review queue. Presently, this answer doesn't provide any additional value / information compared to directly asking an LLM. It could be improved (by verifying &/or explaining the code) so I'm not recommending deletion. But it also isn't particular useful in its present state.
